# Export it - Zoo Visitor

Tags: zoo-visitor, export, csv

Has anyone used the following add-on 'Export it' : https://mithra62.com/projects/feature/export-it/

I am looking to export all Zoo visitor members from the database and I've had no joy with "AJW_Export". Anyone any advice if this add-on does the job?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoo Visitor stores data as channel entires so you should be fine using Export It since it allows exporting of channel data. I have not personally tried exporting Zoo Visitor data but I assume passwords might be your only issue since they are not stored in the DB as plain text but are salted.